# How to assign file-name to Azure DocumentDB attachment?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am uploading an image to documentDb. I assign filename to `slug` property. I retrieve the attachement using `media link` obtained during upload.

My expectation is that when I retrieve attachment I would get my filename back. But in contrary Azure returned `slug` as null. I have double checked content of the retrieved attachement is correct.

Two questions:

1. Am I misusing `slug` property?
2. Where should I assign custom properties?

Here is my Code:

```
public async Task<string> UploadAttachment(string selfLinkId, Stream mediaStream, string contentType, string fileName)
{            
    Document foundDocument = (await _client.ReadDocumentAsync(selfLinkId)).Resource;
    ResourceResponse<Attachment> resp = await _client.CreateAttachmentAsync(foundDocument.AttachmentsLink, mediaStream, new MediaOptions { ContentType = contentType, Slug = fileName, });
    string mediaLink = resp.Resource.MediaLink;
    return mediaLink;
}

public async Task<MediaResponse> GetAttachment(string mediaLink)
{
    //Use DocumentClient to read the Media content
    MediaResponse content = await _client.ReadMediaAsync(mediaLink);
    return content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the content type is being set correctly?

As per [this documentation,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn803933.aspx) slug and contentype are needed only when uploading raw media, which is your scenario. Also, have you checked the Documents Explorer in the azure portal to see how the document and its attachments are stored? Are the values shown there the ones you are expecting?

As per the same documentation, this is an example of how a POST of raw media should look like:

```
POST https://contosomarketing.documents.azure.com/dbs/hUwBcw==/colls/hUwBc+gfDX4=/docs/hUwBc+gfDX4DAAAAAAAAAA==/attachments HTTP/1.1
x-ms-date: Thu, 14 Aug 2014 22:40:25 GMT
authorization: type%3dmaster%26ver%3d1.0%26sig%3dza46lCo9nNr0%2fGMjryG8S%2b26ZsFABUYPlW3ebq26nDg%3d
x-ms-version: 2014-08-21
Content-Type: image/png
Slug: brush.png
Content-Length: 244
```